# Can I use SproutCore without Ruby?

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

SproutCore is said to be a JavaScript framework, so how to use it entirely without Ruby (actually with PHP or Java) on server side?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but looks like it might be possible. Did you see this page? http://wiki.sproutcore.com/Todos+06-Building+with+PHP

Comment: Yes, but it does not explain how to do the client/JS part, client is still Ruby-provided in this case as far as I understand.

Comment: If you questions, visit the IRC chat room at #sproutcore or check out the mailing list at sproutcore@googlegroups.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the build tools are written in ruby.  Unless you want to roll your own I don't think you will be able to do things like build your client side code or use sc-server without ruby.

That said, the build tools are just a set of tools to help you develop.  SC doesn't care what you have on the server.  As long as your server returns json, you are good to go.

In fact, you can build a lot of your client side functionality without the server using fixtures

http://wiki.sproutcore.com/DataStore-Using+Fixtures

Comment: Also, if your app doesn't need to communicate between multiple computers then you can also set up an HTML5 local store.

Answer (score 0):

As hvgotcodes said, for development you'll need Ruby for the build tools. However, there are also some node.js tools available if you'd rather go that route. Furthermore, there is strong interest in making a build tools binary. This would allow SC development without having to install Ruby locally.